# Prove that $\hat{h}_1(S) = \hat{h}_2(S)$ in propositional logic.

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I have the following task:

"For all sentences $S$ of propositional logic and for all evaluation functions $h_1$ and $h_2$, if $h_1$ & $h_2$ match for all atomic sentences in S, then $\hat{h}_1(S) = \hat{h}_2(S)$ obtains."

---

Progress so far:

**Definitions**:

h: The truth assignment function from the set of the atomic sentences of a language to the set $\{T,F\}$

$\hat{h}$: The result of extending h with the following rules:

1. $\hat{h}(Q) = h(Q)$ for the atomic sentences Q.
2. $\hat{h}(\perp) = F$
3. $\hat{h}(\neg Q) = T$ iff $\ \hat{h}(Q) = F$
4. $\hat{h}(Q \land R) = T$ iff $\ \hat{h}(Q) = \hat{h}(R) = T$
5. $\hat{h}(Q \lor R) = F$ iff $\ \hat{h}(Q) = \hat{h}(R) = F$
6. $\hat{h}(Q \to R) = F$ iff $\ \hat{h}(Q) = T \ \& \ \hat{h}(R) = F$
7. $\hat{h}(Q \leftrightarrow R) = T$ iff $\ \hat{h}(Q) = \hat{h}(R)$

Atomic sentence: "A ... [sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_sentence)  which is either true or false ... and which cannot be broken down into other simpler sentences".

**Interpretation**

In my own words, I would begin by trying to make the following statements:

If $h_1$ and $h_2$ match for all atomic sentences in S, then they assign the always same truth values. Then, any time where $h_1$ is true, $h_2$ is true (and visa versa). Maybe I could apply this information to the definitions given for $\hat{h}$ to show that this logically implies that the extensions $\hat{h}_1$ and $\hat{h}_2$ must exhibit identical behavior (i.e, be true under the same conditions).

Am I thinking in the right direction?

If so, how can I formally state this as a proof?

Comment: If you take an algebraic perspective, what the theorem is saying is that the formulas are freely generated from the atomic formulas and so every homomorphism is completely determined by its action on the generating elements, i.e. the atomic formulas.

Comment: You can prove it by induction on the complexity (i.e. the composition) of the formula $S$. If the formula $S$ is atomic, eiher is a single prop letter $p_1$ or is $\bot$. In both cases, $\hat h_1$ and $\hat h_2$ reduce respectively to $h_1$ and $h_2$, and it is done.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Even if this is relatively simple, would you mind giving me a hand with this?

Comment: Do  you know how a proof by induction works ? W ehave to start from the *base* case : see above, the case for $S$ atomic and $S=\bot$.

Comment: The you have to consider the *inductive step*, i.e. assume that the property holds for formula $S$ with $n$ occurrences of *conncetives*, prove that it holds also for $S'$ with $n+1$ occurrences.

Comment: This part of the proof splits according to the number of conenctives. Consider the first sub-case: $\lnot$. We have that $S'=\lnot S$ and we assume that $\hat h_1(S)=\hat h_2(S)$. We have that $\hat h_1(S')=\hat h_1(\lnot S)=\hat h_2(\lnot S)=\hat h_2(S')$. First and last equalities hold by def of $S'$, while the middle one holds by the assuption of the induction step.